# Написание чата на Java. Help!

Tags: java, сервер, клиент-сервер, чат, клиент

Вопрос такой, как мне отправлять сообщения всем пользователям в чате, а не только тому кто его прислал? Подскажите, желательно без вспомогательного класса который обрабатывает подключения

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Server extends Thread{
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private Socket socket;
    private static List<MyClient>clients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    private MyClient client;

    public Server(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            whileChating();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
    private void whileChating() throws IOException {
        String message = "SERVER msg: you are connecting " + socket.getInetAddress() + " : " + socket.getPort();
        printWriter.println(message + "\r\n");
        do {
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            printWriter.println("Сообщение получил");
            printWriter.println(message);
            System.out.println(message);
        }while (!message.equals("EXIT"));
    }
    private void closeConnection(){
        System.out.println("Закрыите соединения");
        printWriter.println("Пользователь отключился \r\n");
        try {
            printWriter.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Запуск сервера:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5656, 25)) {
            while (true){
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Server(socket).start();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyClient extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userInputText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private Socket socket;

    public MyClient(){
        super("Client");
        userInputText = new JTextField();
        userInputText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                userInputText.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(userInputText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        chatWindow.setEditable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        startClient();
    }
    private void startClient() {
        try {
            connectServer();
            whileChating();
        }catch (EOFException e){
            showMessage("Клиент оборвал соединение");
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
    private void connectServer() throws IOException {
        showMessage("Connecting...");
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 5656), 2000);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        showMessage("Connection ready");
    }
    private void whileChating() throws IOException {
        String message;
        do {
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        }while (!message.equals("EXIT"));
    }
    private void closeConnection(){
        showMessage("\nClose connection...");
        try {
            printWriter.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        printWriter.println(message);
    }
    private void showMessage(String msg){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatWindow.append(msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Подскажите как правильно добавить клиентов в коллекцию, чтобы отослать им всем сообщения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант:

У клиента:

- проходить регистрацию на сервере, с получением id
- отправлять сообщения на сервер вместе со своим id

На сервере:

- вместо списка клиентов завести Map
- когда клиент заходит в чат заносить его в map, ключ - id клиента, id отправлять обратно.
- при отправке сообщения от клиента, брать его id исключать из map и отправлять сообщение всем оставшимся.

Comment: Как понять пункт:
проходить регистрацию на сервере, с получением id
И какое сообщение отправлять на сервер вместе с id?

Comment: @Андрей у вас есть список клиентов чата, как они туда попадают?

Comment: нет, как раз хочу это сделать, но не знаю как

Comment: @Андрей зачем вы создаете сервер для каждого клиента? Сервер должен быть 1 для всех клиентов - это первая проблема из которой вытекают последующий. Перепишите код так, чтобы все клиенты общались на одном сервере. В данном коде, где каждому клиенту выдан личный сервер невозможно организовать общение между клиентами. Хотя возможно конечно, но ужасными костылями. Лучше остановитесь сейчас и переделайте под 1 сервер - много клиентов.

Comment: @Андрей сейчас вам придется писать не общение между клиентами, а общение между серверами. Что менее удобно и более трудоемко, ну и читается сложнее

Comment: Классная идея, подскажите как её реализовать, а то где не смотрел используется именно концепция что каждый клиент открывается в новом потоке

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69132/discussion-between--and-).